# How do I run a function on an activity when going back to it?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have an application which executes an AsyncTask onCreate().

The AsyncTask gets movie details from an API and adds the title, poster and overview to a listview. onPostExecute the listview is added with an adaptor.

```
listView.setAdaptor(adaptorxx);
```

After the AsyncTask finishes and it adds the adaptor to the listView the user can then press on an item in the listView which will then putExtra some movie information to another activity called DetailsActivity. This activity shows details about the movie.. a function on this activity is to add the movie to "watched list"

NOW:

How can I make it so that when I go back to the movies listview activity, the listview is updated with the watched movies list?

I tried putting

```
listView.setAdaptor(null);
Adaptor adaptorxx = new Adaptor(xxx, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx);
listView.setAdaptor(adaptorxx);
```

in onResume after creating an onPause, didn't work, i also tried adding it to onRestart but that didn't work either

Comment: [StartActivityforResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) is what you need.

Comment: you can use 1) startActivityforResult or 2) use interface listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing you the example of `StartActivityForResult`

There are two variants of startActivityForResult() method.

```
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)  
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)
```

Example Below

**ActivityOne**

Pass your intent like this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
```

Then Add `onActivityResult` where you got the data from the Second activity

```
// Call Back method  to get the Message from secondActivity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

**ActivityTwo**

Pass intent like below so you can get intent object in `onActivityResult` and fetch your data from it.

```
  Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity
```

**NOTE :** After adding that data you have to referesh your adapter using `notifyDatasetChanged()` method.